# React Native: "Cannot find native module" error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-native-module, native-module

In my React Native app, I'm trying to add the `expo-mail-composer` package using [this guide](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/mail-composer/).

I use `react-native@0.64.0`,
I added `"install-expo-modules": "^0.2.8"`,
then `"expo-mail-composer": "~11.3.0"`,

When I try to import the package with

```js
import * as MailComposer from 'expo-mail-composer'
```

it throws the error

```bash
Cannot find native module 'ExpoMailComposer'
```

Comment: are you using expo-cli or react-native-cli? if you using expo cli then no need to add dependency or if you using react-native-cli then you should import its package to the respective platform android or ios

Answer (score 4):

This issue was resolved for me by creating a new development build:

```
eas build --profile development --platform android
```

Then downloading and installing that build on my device:

```
adb install --user 0 <path_to_apk>
```

I then ran the app with:

```
set APP_ENV=development&& npx expo start --dev-client
```

The app opened as normal after that, and `MailComposer.composeAsync()` appears to work.

(For reference, I'm developing on a physical Android device using the Managed workflow, and did not have to use `npx install-expo-modules@latest`.)

Comment: Fixed my error for ExpoSharing. Seems odd that an Expo module requires a new Dev build, and that the Expo doc mentions nothing about needing a new Dev build. but oh well. Seems to fix my error too.

Answer (score 1):

To use expo modules in a non-expo project (*aka bare workflow*), you need to **install Expo modules** first with:

```
npx install-expo-modules@latest
```

https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/